Laravel 10 with FilamentPHP 3 - Overlapping Date Range Validation
How to prevent date overlapping for existing date range in database?
I have SchoolPeriod model and school_periods table with date_from and date_to columns and it is defined as protected fillable for mass assignment.
I already generated a filament resource for SchoolPeriod and I want to have a validation for date_from and date_to Forms\Components\DatePicker. If the date_from or date_to is already exists in the date range of exsisting records in the database, flash a validation message.
SchoolPeriod Migration:
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('school_periods', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->date('date_from');
            $table->date('date_to');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unique(['date_from', 'date_to']);
        });
    }

SchoolPeriod Model for protected fillable:
    protected $fillable = [
        'date_from',
        'date_to',
        'name',
        'is_active',
        'created_by',
    ];

SchoolPeriodResource Form:
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\DatePicker::make('date_from')
                    ->label('Start Date')
                    ->required()
                    ->beforeOrEqual('date_to'),
                Forms\Components\DatePicker::make('date_to')
                    ->label('End Date')
                    ->required()
                    ->afterOrEqual('date_from')
                    ->unique(modifyRuleUsing: function(Unique $rule, callable $get){
                        $start = $get('date_from');
                        $end = $get('date_to');
                        return $rule->where(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
                            $q->where('date_from', '>=', $start)
                            ->where('date_from', '<=', $end);
                        })
                        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
                            $q->where('date_to', '>=', $start)
                                ->where('date_to', '<=', $end);
                        })
                        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
                            $q->where('date_from', '<', $start)
                                ->where('date_to', '>', $end);
                        });
                    }),
            ]);
    }


The orWhere method is undefined.

Use a custom validation rule for the dates to check if they overlap with any existing record in the database.

This should work, comments have been inserted to explain the code:
 public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            DatePicker::make('date_from')
                ->label('Start Date')
                ->required()
                ->beforeOrEqual('date_to')
                // Enable live updating, required for disabled rule, see below
                ->live(),
            DatePicker::make('date_to')
                ->label('End Date')
                ->required()
                ->afterOrEqual('date_from')
                // disable the date_to field to force the users to select the date_from first
                ->disabled(fn(Get $get): bool => !$get('date_from'))
                ->rules([
                    function (Get $get) {
                    // Define a custom validation rule to check for overlapping school periods
                        return function (string $attribute, $value, Closure $fail) use ($get) {
                            $start = $get('date_from');
                            $end = $get('date_to');
                            // Query the SchoolPeriod model to check for any existing periods that overlap with the selected date range.
                            $exists = SchoolPeriod::whereBetween('date_from', [$start, $end]) // Check if date_from is between 'start' and 'end'
                                ->orWhereBetween('date_to', [$start, $end]) // // Check if date_to is between 'start' and 'end'
                                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
                                    $query->where('date_from', '>', $start)
                                        ->where('date_to', '<', $end);
                                })->exists();

                            if($exists) {
                                $fail('The dates overlap');
                            }

                            
                        };
                    },
                ])
        ]);
}

You can simplify query for overlapping intervals with this trick.
Something like this:
$exists =SchoolPeriod::whereRaw('GREATEST(date_from, ?) < LEAST(date_to, ?)', [$start, $end])
                                ->exists();

Maybe you should consider a custom validation rule.
